# Кастомные названия DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatable

Хочу изменить текст "Previous" и "Next" на свой вариант.
[image: Верный XHTML]
Исходя из документации [раз](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language), [два](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/i18n#oLanguage.sSearch) я нашел:

```
//первый вариант
"paginate": {
        "next":       "Вперед",
        "previous":   "Назад"
    },

//второй
"sNext": "Next page"
```

Но значения не изменяются, даже когда кнопки активны.

```
$('#phones').DataTable({
            //не работает
            "language": {
                "paginate": {
                    "next":       "Вперед",
                    "previous":   "Назад"
                },
            },
            //не работает
            "oLanguage": {
                "paginate": {
                    "next":       "Вперед",
                    "previous":   "Назад"
                },
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо прописать  `language`.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "next":       "Вперед",
                "previous":   "Назад"
             },
        }
});
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, не помогло...

Comment: @Tarasovych очень странно, проверь правильность id и подключения скриптов, тк я проверил на своей таблице и все работает.

Comment: Странно, у меня уже есть некоторые атрибуты в `$('#myTable').DataTable({...});`, и `language` не хочет работать с ними в одном селекторе (`oLanguage`, если конкретно). А если вынести отдельно - работает. Перенес из `oLanguage` в `language` и все заработало.